# How to fill area below geom_line plot in ggplot with geom_rect?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
economics <- economics %>% mutate(year = year(economics$date))

ggplot(economics,aes(year, unemploy))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1970,xmax = 1975,
                     ymin = 0, ymax = unemploy))
```

I want to fill the area below the line plot between the years 1970 and 1975. But it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to fill below the whole line? can you explain/show your desired plot in more detail?

Comment: @bird yeas. I know that I can use others geom_* but how can I do this with geom_rect?

Comment: If you want to fill the whole area under the line why are you specifying `xmin = 1970,xmax = 1975`? (just trying to first understand your code)

Comment: It is not clear why it is not filling. Using this reproducible example `set.seed(24);
economics <- data.frame(year = 1970:1990, unemploy = sample(5:10, 21, replace = TRUE))` is giving the filled one with your code

Comment: Sorry, I was checking before loading the package. thanks

Comment: Your edited code shows `ymax` as the whole column instead of a single value

Comment: I thought that geom_rect uses the correspondents values automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in `ymax` we are using the whole column 'unemploy', it should be the `max` value of 'unemploy' within that range of year

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
economics %>%
    mutate(year = year(date)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(year, unemploy)) + 
        geom_line() +
   geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1970,xmax = 1975,
                      ymin = 0,
        ymax = max(.data[['unemploy']][between(.data[['year']], 1970, 1975)]))) + 
    theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose a `ymax` that makes sense to you. For example, I set `ymax = 4800`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(economics,aes(year, unemploy))+
        geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1970,xmax = 1975,
                      ymin = 0, ymax = 4800), fill = "lightblue", alpha = .5) +
        geom_line()
```

[image]